# signing Keys for CyanogenMod

Tags: android

I'm using CyanogenMod-6.1.1-Spica-alpha8.3 mod version. I want to change and install one system application. I have successfully build the system application in eclipse. But don't know which keys shud I use to sign the generated apk so that it could be installed as update to the system application. Please if anyone can throw the light on the issue it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with this recently, and in order for it to install as an update you have to use the same key you used previously. Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) for reference, specifically under the "Signing Strategies" section.

This is assuming you are talking about a standard android application that you have built. You say "system application" which leads me to believe you may be talking about something else (like a built in application or something?) - but that does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks. Yup I 've already gone thorough the link but I don know what signing keys does Cynogen Mod used to sign and then build the mod. I guess without those signing keys it would be hard to give update to built in applications.

Answer (score 3):

Today was trying to change and install CyanogenMod system app. Was able to it after signing with platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem keys. You can get the keys from: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_build/tree/gingerbread/target/product/security